# How to make rest call to _vti_history for getting any previous version file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, version-history

I want to make rest call or implement some JSOM mechanism to retrieve previous version file from `_vti_history`.

For example: `_vti_history/1024/Documents/Filename.docx`

Please guide me if this is possible in some way.

Thanks,

Kailash

Answer (score 3):

You can use below to get file versions history, there is rest endpoint available which will give you all version of a file using item id, also it can be done using JSOM.

REST API

```
/sites/yoursite/_api/Web/Lists(@v0)/Items(@v1)/Versions?&@v0=guid'112313-13cebe-1233-822e-asd123123123'&@v1=10
```

JSOM (ref [link](http://www.codesharepoint.com/jsom/get-all-file-versions-in-sharepoint-using-jsom))

```
var oItems, clientContext, oFile, oFileVersions;
function GetAllVersions() {
    // You can optionally specify the Site URL here to get the context
    // If you don't specify the URL, the method will get the context of the current site
    // var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/SiteCollection");
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

    // Get List Object
    var olistCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    var oList = olistCollection.getByTitle("Documents");

    // Get Item using CAML Query
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'FileLeafRef\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'File\'>Document.docx</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    oItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    // Load List Item collection object
    clientContext.load(oItems);

    // Execute the query to the server.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfailed);
}

function onsuccess() {
    // Loop through each Item.
    var itemCount = oItems.get_count();
    for (var i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++) {
        // Get File object of the list item
        oFile = oItems.itemAt(i).get_file();
        oFileVersions = oFile.get_versions();
        clientContext.load(oFileVersions);

        break;
    }

    //Execute the batch
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(FinalQuerySuccess, FinalQueryFailure);
}

function onfailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function FinalQuerySuccess(sender, args) {

    // Iterate through Enumerator
    var oEnumerator = oFileVersions.getEnumerator();
    while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oFile = oEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log("Version Label : " + oFile.get_versionLabel());
        console.log("Version Comment : " + oFile.get_checkInComment());
    }
}

function FinalQueryFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Your code gives all the version labels for the file.my requiremet is to get eaxct file of any specific version.Any idea to get it